# Write a cmd line script to parse an xml file

Tags: command-line, scripting

What would be the best solution to check (from the command line with a script), if a certain xml file contains this line:

```
<endpoint uri="endpoint.php" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
```

or this line

```
<!-- <endpoint uri="endpoint.php" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/> -->
```

and stop execution if the second one (commented out) is found?

Thx,
martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming pattern occurs at single line

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
/<endpoint uri=.*endpoint.php.*class.*flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint/ && /<!--/{
    exit
}
/<endpoint uri=.*endpoint.php.*class.*flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint/{
    # to execute external script inside awk, uncomment below
    #cmd = "myscript.sh"
    #system(cmd)
} 
' file
```

OR you can return a code back to shell

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(awk '
/<endpoint uri=.*endpoint.php.*class.*flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint/ && /<!--/{
    print 1
}
/<endpoint uri=.*endpoint.php.*class.*flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint/{
    print 0
} 
' file)
[ "$var" -eq 1 ] && exit
[ "$var" -eq 0 ] && ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: These are not totally reliable. A node called <endpoints (note the extra s) would mess things up.

Comment: its OP's sample, not mine. If there is possibility of "s" in endpoint, then matching it exactly will do.

Comment: this looks good! It is sufficient how it is checked. I am trying to execute a script in the second case...
just putting a command in there does not work for me
e.g. (./doSomething.sh)
do I need to use exec()?

Answer (score 4):

Single line or across multiple lines? If the former, you can use `grep`.

*Update*: There seem to be some XML aware variants like [xgrep](http://www.wohlberg.net/public/software/xml/xgrep/), [xmltwig](http://www.xmltwig.com/) and [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).